# Is there a notepad++ plugin to display open files as a side panel

Tags: notepad++

Is there a plugin that will make the open file show up in a side panel instead of a tab.

My monitor is in portrait mode and I don't have much horizontal real estate, the tab will show 6 files at most.

Comment: I don't get this. The Tabs will start to cascade vertically when the horizontal real estate runs out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for the "Document List" button that lets you
show or hide the document list vertically on the left:

[image: "Document List" button]

Comment: I don't have the same Icon set, but I was able to find it under View->Document List! will accept the answer as soon as it let me! Thank you!